# sys.path in python3 contains path for python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pythonpath

I recently installed python3 in my MacOs.

Here's what `sys.path` gives me on the python3 interpreter:

`['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Users/rdora', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`

As you can see, the first entry belongs to the site-packages of python2.7.

Moreover, `$pip3 list` returns:

`biopython (1.68)
fisher (0.1.4)
mpmath (0.19)
networkx (1.11)
numpy (1.11.2)
pickleshare (0.7.4)
pip (9.0.1)
scipy (0.18.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
sympy (1.0)`

but `$sudo pip3 list` gives:

`biopython (1.69)
numpy (1.12.1)
pip (9.0.1)
scipy (0.19.0)
setuptools (28.8.0)`

The first list of packages coincide with the packages I've installed for python2 with `$pip install PackageName` and the second list with the packages I recently installed with `$sudo pip3 install PackageName`.

Any idea why I get this different results depending on the use of `sudo`, and why is there a python2 path in `sys.path` for python3?

Note: I installed python 2.7 using brew and python3 using the installer from [PSF](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/).

Comment: To save you the long discussion I would suggest installing [virtualenv](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenv) to setup your environment for python projects. That way you can don't have to worry about the root packages vs user packages etc.